Why does this output skip palindromes?
I'm following a tutorial on generators from https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/, and in the section about .send(), the code does not output the sequence I expect.
This is the code:
def is_palindrome(num):
    # Skip single-digit inputs
    if num // 10 == 0:
        return False
    temp = num
    reversed_num = 0

    while temp != 0:
        reversed_num = (reversed_num * 10) + (temp % 10)
        temp = temp // 10

    if num == reversed_num:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def infinite_palindromes():
    num = 0
    while True:
        if is_palindrome(num):
            i = (yield num)
            if i is not None:
                num = i
        num += 1

pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
for i in pal_gen:

    digits = len(str(i))
    pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))

I thought that the code would generate 11, 101, 1001, 10001, and so on, but instead it generates 11, 111, 1111, 10101, 101101, 1001001, 10011001, and so on. Why is this? It seems that it is skipping 101, 1001, and 10001, for some reason, as those should be the next closest palindromes after every power of 10 that is sent back to the generator.

How are you determining what numbers are generated?  There's no print() or other output in the code you posted!  I think your basic problem is that the generator is being advanced twice per iteration of the loop - once from the for loop itself (assigned to i) and once when you call .send() (you ignore this value).

When I add print(i) to the  for loop I get 11, 10011001, and 10000011000001. It takes a long time to generate each number, I gave up waiting at this point.

The send method not only sends a value back to the generator, it also RETURNS the next thing that is yielded.  So, when you generate "11", that results in "digits" being 2, so you pal.gen(100).  The generator then continues to execute, until it yields "101".  That becomes the return value of the send, but you drop that on the floor.  The generator then continues to the next palindrome, "111".
Again, that triggers the digits thing, which sends "1000".  The next palindrome is "1001", which again is dropped on the floor, and you get "1111".
The send thing is a rather advanced and seldom used feature.  I didn't know it existed until your question.

As mentioned in the comments, you're stepping the generator twice in each iteration -- one is automatic from the for-in statement, the other is from calling pal_gen.send(). But only one of these is sending a new value back to the generator, and you're discarding the result of the other.
Change your loop to this:
pal_gen = infinite_palindromes()
i = next(pal_gen)
while True:
    print(i)
    digits = len(str(i))
    i = pal_gen.send(10 ** (digits))

This steps the generator just once in each iteration, and captures the result of it in the i variable.
This produces the expected sequence:
11
101
1001
10001
100001
1000001
10000001
...


In your requirement, you left out few numbers like 111, 1111 etc.,
As I didn't check your function is_polyndrome, I created another one. If your is_polyndrome works alright, you can ignore my is_polyndrome function.
I've given my is_polyndrome here so that you can check for my logics as well.
def is_polyndrome(num):

    str_num = str(num) #convert to string

    L = len(str_num) # length of the string

    head_idx = L//2

    if L%2 == 0: # If the length of the string is even
        tail_idx = head_idx
    
    # If the length of the string is odd, ignore the middle character
    else:   
        tail_idx = head_idx + 1

    head = str_num[:head_idx] # first half of the string

    tail = str_num[tail_idx:] # second half of the string

    tail =tail[::-1] # reverse the second half

    if head == tail: 
        return num
    return None
    
i = 2
while True:
    binary = int(bin(i)[2:]) # convert into binary
    res = is_polyndrome(binary) 
    
    if res is not None:
        print(res)
    
    i  += 1

Output:
11
101
111
1001
1111
10001
10101
11011
11111
100001
101101
110011
111111
1000001
1001001
-------
-------

